# Meteor Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

When I am trying to load the following package in Meteor https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection

It gets downloaded 100% and extracted, but at the time of loading it throws the following error:

```
{ [
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\LALITS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mt-16riklk\npm\job\node_modules']
  errno: -4051,
  code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\LALITS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\mt-16riklk\\npm\\job\\node_modules' }
```

I am using windows 8.1 64 bit. 
I have tried to delete the folder manually, but again it created a new one and throws the same error. Can anyone tell me what is the problem? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got any old versions still running? Have you tried a reboot of the machine?

Comment: yes, i had rebooted the machine and checked.

Comment: I am using Meteor 1.4.4.3

Comment: Are you running this from the command line? If so, are you running that command prompt with Administrator privileges?

Comment: Yes, i am running it with the administrator privileges.

Comment: Deleting the directory path shown, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like this known Meteor bug:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8663. This bug occurs under Windows when updating to the next Meteor version.

Maybe you can try the proposed solution, which is to edit the following file:

```
C:\Users\[yourName]\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\[yourMeteorVersion]\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\fs\files.js
```

...and replace functions `files.rm_recursive_async` and `files.rm_recursive` with this code:

```
files.rm_recursive_async = function (path) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    rimraf(files.convertToOSPath(path), function (err) {
      err &&  console.log(err);
      resolve();
      //return err ? reject(err) : resolve();
    });
  });
}; // Like rm -r.

files.rm_recursive = Profile("files.rm_recursive", function (path) {
  try {
    rimraf.sync(files.convertToOSPath(path));
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.code === "ENOTEMPTY" && canYield()) {
      files.rm_recursive_async(path).await();
      return;
    }

    console.log(e);
    //throw e;
  }
}); // Makes all files in a tree read-only.
```